# Getting input/output error running anything on remote desktop

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop

I installed Xfce and I'm trying to use VPS over remote desktop.

When I connect and try to run anything ( tried terminal and browser so far ) I'm getting this:

[image: Failed to execute default Terminal Emulator. Input/output Error.]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It's probably your virtual hard drive.
Please check if it's in read-only mode and try to fix it (fsck can help).

Answer (score 11):

If those methods don't help, you can try this.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal

sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Select xfce4-terminal.

Comment: In my case I had to install the xfce-terminal first before I could select it with the 2nd line, making this the more "complete" solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to update the default terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Then choose the Xfce4 terminal (or any other from a package providing terminal-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what exactly i did, but...

1. reinstalled VPS
2. sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
3. then followed https://www.tweaking4all.com/software/linux-software/use-xrdp-remote-access-ubuntu-14-04/

I used few other tutorials, similar, but all of then were giving me input/output error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have replaced another terminal with the default terminal. Just search and go to the default application settings and replace the default terminal.

[image: Screenshot]